# Why Comparable implementation working

Tags: java, oop

Can anybody explain me why below code is working on private member variable?

```
    public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String firstName;
    public Person(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(o.firstName);  // why does it work?    }    }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Why `o.firstName` is getting compile ? where firstName is `private` variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The access modifiers control access per class rather than per instance. So, methods of class `T` can access all members (even private) of other class `T`'s instances.

The [Access Control from JLS 7 link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6) for the curious. It says, *"Note that accessibility is a static property that can be determined at compile time; it **depends only on types and declaration modifiers**."*

Comment: +1. Alexander, a link to relevant JLS section would complete this answer.

Comment: Yep, had found it but had to leave my desk for a while :)

Answer (score 3):

Because [private variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) are visible within the class that declares them, and `o` is a `Person`.

Comment: Thats true but here we are not calling `firstName` locally, we are calling this through object.private in some other class ?

Comment: What other class? Both the `firstName` declaration and access is within `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

The method "compareTo" is implemented in the "Person" class which naturally has access to it's private members. You override the method from the interface Comparable. So you are working with the same class in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Because objects of the same class can access each others private properties. This does not entirely break the separation of concerns because the code for such accesses must be in the same class so the class is still responsible for the property.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the private members inside the class, that declares them, which is perfectly ok.

The declaring class always has access to all of its members, regardless of which instance of the class the members belong to.

Thus the following code compiles and works.

```
public class AClass {
    private String name;
    public AClass(String n) {name = n;}

    public void mock(AClass other) {
        System.out.pritln(this.name + ": \"" + other.name + " smells.\"");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AClass a = new AClass("Bully");
        AClass b = new AClass("Nemesis");
        a.mock(b);
    }
}
```